# What phrases should you avoid using to make your question a true question.

Tags: discussion, questions

Basically what phrases should one beware of when writing. The type of open ended, subjective stuff that does not belong here as its too argumentative and has no real answer.

Answer (score 7):

"What is the best way to…" is to be avoided. The problem with that phrase is that it is asking the *answerers* to determine the best answer, and then write it. That shortcuts the Stack Exchange process where people just answer, and then the community determines the "best" answer by voting.

Asking for "the best" of anything is a meta-question: it's a question about the potential answers (i.e., which answer is best), not asking for the potential answers directly.

A better way to phrase this would be "How can I…", which asks for a direct answer to the problem and leaves the community to sort the answers by quality.

Comment: agreed.  there seem to be a lot of these here...

Answer (score 1):

“Normally this question would be highly subjective” if you have to say this then chances are the answers to this question will be subjective as well. Make sure you are asking questions that can have definitive answers. There are plenty of places for subjective argumentative fights on the web. This is a place to ask questions and get an answer that solves your problem.

“Hopefully the answers will…” if you have to hope that you’ll get answers that are useful you probably didn’t ask a good enough question.